# I need help making sure all necessary drivers are installed and working Help?

Tags: sound, graphics, intel

I'm setting up a desktop for the first time and having issues with making sure all the drivers for sound and graphics work.  I looked for any troubleshooters and there are none to be found.  I am new to Ubuntu and using 16.04

Answer (score 0):

> having issues with making sure all the drivers for sound and graphics work

You can try Checkbox

Press the [Super key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key), type Checkbox and run it.

Comment: I did, but static comes through my speakers.

Comment: That's a different issue from you asked here, try replugging it, make sure cables are intact etc. If the issue persists, search for question here and ask new one if you can't find a good question about it.

Comment: I figured out the graphics part. all the cables and connections are good and securely connected.  All I'm really looking for is a troubleshooter.